# Scan for secured pdf documents

Tags: python, pypdf

I've currently run into the need to find which pdfs within a directory are "Secured Documents".
All of the pdfs **should** be unsecured, and convertible via xpdf, however, this is not the case. How could I scan through all the pdfs in a directory to find out whether or not they are secured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) supports decrypting PDFs. Its PdfReader class has an [is_encrypted](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#pypdf.PdfReader.is_encrypted) attribute.

```
import pypdf
if pypdf.PdfReader("file_name.pdf").is_encrypted:
    print("Rut ro, it's encrypted.")
    # skip file? Write to a log?
else:
    print("We're clear.")
    # Do stuff with the file.
```